# CMake 2.8.10.2 fails with Xcode 4.6

Tags: ios, xcode, cmake, allegro, allegro5

I'm trying to build the [Allegro](http://alleg.sf.net) 5.0.8 game library for iOS and it seems CMake 2.8.10.2 is failing with Xcode 4.6:

```
localhost:build steve$ cmake -DCMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE=../cmake/Toolchain-iphone.cmake -G Xcode ..
-- The C compiler identification is Clang 4.2.0
-- The CXX compiler identification is Clang 4.2.0
-- Check for working C compiler using: Xcode
-- Check for working C compiler using: Xcode -- broken
CMake Error at /usr/local/Cellar/cmake/2.8.10.2/share/cmake/Modules/CMakeTestCCompiler.cmake:61 (message):
  The C compiler
  "/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang"
  is not able to compile a simple test program.

  It fails with the following output:

   Change Dir: /Users/steve/DEV/allegro/allegro-5.0.8/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp



  Run Build Command:/usr/local/Cellar/cmake/2.8.10.2/bin/cmakexbuild -project
  CMAKE_TRY_COMPILE.xcodeproj build -target cmTryCompileExec2759687021
  -configuration Debug

  === BUILD NATIVE TARGET cmTryCompileExec2759687021 OF PROJECT
  CMAKE_TRY_COMPILE WITH CONFIGURATION Debug ===

  Check dependencies

  target specifies product type 'com.apple.product-type.tool', but there's no
  such product type for the 'iphoneos' platform





  ** BUILD FAILED **





  The following build commands failed:

    Check dependencies

  (1 failure)





  CMake will not be able to correctly generate this project.
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  CMakeLists.txt:31 (project)


-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
localhost:build steve$ cmake --version
cmake version 2.8.10.2
localhost:build steve$
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Did you try running the mentioned compiler (clang) to see if it is in fact broken?

Comment: Clang works. I just successfully compile and ran a simple Hello World.

Comment: Oh great, looks like an open bug. http://cmake.org/Bug/view.php?id=12288

Comment: Still happening in Xcode 5. Ugh.

Comment: Still happening in OSX 10.9 !!

Comment: Well let's see how we go with Yosemite.